# App store submission errors

Tags: ios, xcode

I have developed an app , an ready for distribution to app store. I am following the guide step by step.BUT when I use Application Upload, it shows [this image](http://ppt.cc/Ko7C):

[image: error messages]

Could anyone tell me which step is wrong?

Comment: You've got three different errors there, and they each seem fairly clear. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: Agreed. All the errors are fairly explicit. First of all make sure your bundle ID matches whatever you entered in itunes connect. Next, make sure you are including a default icon for iphone/ipad at 57x57 and then make sure you are code signing correctly with a distribution certificate. If you don't have one you need to log into ios developer portal and create/retrieve it there.

Comment: The error already explains what you are missing. Read & follow the instructions.

Comment: I agree with the posts above, these are all very clearly posted errors, the only one that isn't necessarily self explanatory is the Icon error. Even if your icon is 57x57 you can get this error sometimes from having the image compression bool set to yes in build settings.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, these are the problems:

- The bundle ID "SearchAndBuy.SearchAndBuy" doesn't match the bundle ID that you set up in iTunesConnect.
- You haven't provided a proper icon, or you haven't properly described it in your Info.plist file.
- Your app wasn't properly signed. Some possible reasons are given in the error message.

The real problem here is that you haven't closely followed the instructions for preparing your app as given in the developer portal. Log into the portal, click the Distribution tab, and follow the instructions under "How To". It may be a bit tedious to carefully complete each step, but the reward is a successful submission in less time than it'll take if you're not paying close attention.

Comment: thank you your advice ! what to do now is following the step by step once .

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/AboutYourFirstAppStoreSubmission/AboutYourFirstAppStoreSubmission.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011375